# Мониторинг изменений в реестре

Tags: c#, консоль, реестр

Не выводит запись об изменения в реестре ( вывод в консоль )
По этой статье + примере на программе: [RegistryMonitor](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4502/RegistryMonitor-a-NET-wrapper-class-for-RegNotifyC)

Сделал следующие разделы:

```
static List<string> RegScan = new List<string>()
        {
            @"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runas\command",
            @"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\zapfile\shell\open\command",
            @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.exe",
            @"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe",
        };
```

Далее по этой библиотеки **RegistryUtils.dll**

Сделал массив RegistryMonitor

```
private static RegistryMonitor[] registryMonitors;

public static void StopRegistryMonitor()
{
    if (registryMonitors != null)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<registryMonitors.Length; i++)
        {
            registryMonitors[i].RegChanged -= OnRegistryChanged;
            registryMonitors[i].Dispose();
        }
        registryMonitors = null;
        Console.WriteLine("Monitoring stopped");
    }
}

public static void StartRegistryMonitor()
{
    if (registryMonitors != null) return;

    registryMonitors = new RegistryMonitor[RegScan.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < RegScan.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Monitoring \"" + RegScan[i] + "\" started");
        registryMonitors[i] = new RegistryMonitor(RegScan[i]);
        registryMonitors[i].RegChanged += OnRegistryChanged;
    }
}

static void OnRegistryChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   Console.WriteLine("registry key has changed");
}
```

Запускаю:

```
 Thread s = new Thread(StartRegistryMonitor);
        s.Start();
```

Но при добавление в реестре по нужным веткам(массива) ключа или раздела, не оповещает в консоли :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё верно, просто автор данной статьи написал:

> RegistryMonitor has two public methods which are declared as follows:

```
public void Start();
public void Stop();
```

> **I don't think that these methods require much explanation.** The former creates a separate thread, which will monitor the registry, and the latter will stop that thread.

Это означает что создать инстанс `RegistryMonitor` и подписаться на событие ещё не означает что монитор будет запущен/работать. Соответственно вот так запускаем:

```
public static void StartRegistryMonitor()
{
  if (registryMonitors != null) return;

  registryMonitors = new RegistryMonitor[RegScan.Count];
  for (int i = 0; i < RegScan.Count; i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Monitoring \"" + RegScan[i] + "\" started");
    registryMonitors[i] = new RegistryMonitor(RegScan[i]);
    registryMonitors[i].RegChanged += OnRegistryChanged;
    registryMonitors[i].Start(); // Старт мониторинга тут.
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно)

Comment: Но есть одна проблема, например если удалить какой-то ключ в другом разделе ( не из массива ). То программа это отлавливает почему-то, ( именно при удаление (ключа или раздела). 
С чем это связано?

Comment: @ArteS, хм, у меня эта проблема не воспроизводится. Или Вы что то  не так делаете или давайте более детальное описание Ваших шагов и кода.