# Отслеживать изменения в реестре

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

Мне необходимо отслеживать некоторые изменения в реестре (HKLM, HKCU). Я пытался применить WMI RegistryKeyChangeEvent для решения данной проблемы, но он не поддерживает HKEY_CURRENT_USER. Слышал про функцию RegKeyChangeNotify, но она не возвращает что и как было изменено в реестре. Есть мысль использовать цикл, чтобы отслеживать реестр (точнее определенные ключи), но думаю, что это плохое решение. Товарищи, есть мысли?

Comment: [например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626387/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626387/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5